# print previous string from indexed string

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm looking to index the word `'OPEN'` from a string that has been already split. Then I want to print the 6th string before the indexed word.

```
>>> details = ['Serial#', ':', 'xxx00', 'LV', ':', '0', 'SL', ':',
'0', 'CL', ':', '0', 'TYPE', ':', 'OPEN', etc...]

>>> num = details.index('OPEN')
```

The output I'm looking for is `'0'`.

Comment: Is the splitting character `:`? Why is it still in your list?

Comment: It's from the output from the command I run. I split it and wanted to keep the `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is, the "index" when indexing a sequence (like a list) can be any expression, including subtraction:

```
num = details[details.index('OPEN') - 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard. This is exactly what I was looking for.